# Google listening mode is on while sending an notification for NEW_SURFACE intent

Tags: actions-on-google

In Google action, when user requests a surface shift (NEW_SURFACE intent), Google sends a notification to phone or tablet. When user clicks on the notification to open the Google Action, Google's listening mode is automatic on that causes the Google picks up the reading words and does a google search on these words and terminates the current Google action. This especially happens when the phone was locked while getting notification.

Side note: For Assistant version 1.9.3, when user clicks on notification, the assistant app just repeats the Google surface shift message and user Google action gets terminated. This issue seems to be fixed by version 1.9.5.

Comment: Hi Zoe, what is it that you are asking or need help with? I don't really see a clear question in your message.

Comment: I am reporting a google issue. After surface shift, when user clicks the notification with the phone is locked, the user's Google action ends and instead Google starts Google search action.

Comment: I added more details in below section.

Comment: Hi Zoe, Stackoverflow is not intended for bug reports regarding actions on google. If you wish to report a bug please look at the docs on contacting support directly.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the detail of the issue on iPhone with Google Assistant app V1.9.5

*phone is locked and App is not running*

```
•   Acknowledge Surface shift on device 1
•   Click on Surface Shift notification on device 2
•   Google Assistant app opens

Issue:

•   Mic is open while Assistant is reading initial response.  
•   Mic is picking up the Assistant voice and the app is responding with a generic Google search.  

Fix:

•   Mic should not be opened until Assistant is done reading initial response.
```

*phone is locked and App is running*

```
•   Acknowledge Surface shift on device 1
•   Click on Surface Shift notification on device 2
•   Google Assistant app opens

Issue:

•   Assistant app is not reading the expected initial response.  
•   Instead, it is reading the “Surface Shift” message that was already supplied on device 1.  All voice, no text displayed on screen.

Fix:

•   Should be providing the correct initial response
•   Should not be reading the the “Surface Shift” message
```

*phone is unlocked and App is not running*

```
•   Acknowledge Surface shift on device 1
•   Click on Surface Shift notification on device 2
•   Google Assistant app opens

Issue:

•   Mic is open while Assistant is reading initial response.  
•   Mic is picking up the Assistant voice and the app is responding with a generic Google search.  

Fix:

•   Mic should not be opened until Assistant is done reading initial response.
```

*phone is unlocked and App is running*

```
•   Behaving correctly.  Initial response after shift is read/displayed correctly.  Mic is not opened until the Assistant is done reading initial response.
```